# Which part of the contract is "uninitialized"?

Tags: contract-development

I'm reading [this issue](https://github.com/openethereum/parity-ethereum/issues/6995), and quote:

> I was able to make myself the owner of that contract because its uninitialized.

So I opened [this link](https://etherscan.io/address/0x863df6bfa4469f3ead0be8f9f2aae51c91a907b4) to view the contract, but I didn't find the part that is "uninitialized".

What does he mean here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WalletLibrary` contract is used to provide the logic for all `Wallet` instances. Each instance had to initialized by calling `initWallet` (line 223) with the owners and  other configuration params. This method sets the owners by calling `initMultiowned`. When you now perform an action against an instance the onwership is checked via the `onlymanyowners` (line 95) modifier. To prevent multiple initializations the contracts has a `only_unitialized` (line 219) modifier, which checks if any owners have already been registered.

So this is all expected, the point is that you can do the same with the `WalletLibrary` and take the ownership of it by calling `initWallet`. Once that has been done you can perform any interaction on it, even destroying it via the `kill` method (line 229). Problem is when the `WalletLibrary` code is removed from the blockchain when it is killed, that also all `Wallet` instances lose their functionality.

Some more info: https://www.parity.io/blog/security-alert-2/